# matlab events in parfor loops

Tags: matlab, events, parallel-processing

I have a system that relies on an event, and to speed up the system I tried to parallelize it, however events don't seem to trigger in parallel loops. Since my system is too large I have it boiled down into about 30 lines here (3 files)

```
classdef eventsend < handle
    events
        go
    end
    methods
        function sendit(self)
            notify(self,'go');
        end
    end
end

classdef eventcatch
    methods
        function self = eventcatch(sender)
            addlistener(sender,'go',@self.doSomething);
        end
        function doSomething(varargin)
            disp('HERE');
        end
    end
end

function bug
    send = eventsend();
    eventcatch(send);
    a = @send.sendit;
    a();
    parfor i=1:5
        a();
    end
end
```

This will print `HERE` once, but if the par is removed it will work and print 6 times.

Question: Is there a way I can parallelize it and still have events?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's review what happens when a `parfor` loop gets executed on a pool of local or remote workers:

(0) A separate Matlab instance spawns for each worker.

(1) The variables from the function workspace that are needed inside the loop are written to disk (if the parfor loop runs locally, they aren't *actually* written to disk, but for all practical purposes, it will appear as if they were). If parfor runs remotely, all .m-files get sent to the remote worker as well.

(2) Each Matlab instance loads the variables associated with the iteration they're supposed to evaluate, and runs the body of the `parfor` loop.

Your problem stems from either the fact that events cannot be passed between Matlab instances, or that you do not construct `eventsent`/`eventcatch` on load, which means that they aren't properly listening anymore.

In general, I find it easier to wrap `parfor` loops *around* classes, rather than within methods, so that I do not have to worry about funny side-effects of saving/loading objects.

Comment: Note that for your point (1) - the variables needed inside the `parfor` loop aren't actually written to disk (in the case of an interactive parallel pool), but the effect on `handle` classes (and others) is *as if* they had been written to disk.